# How to edit all Vim highlight groups?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I am going through the unfortunate process of making keybinds to change colorschemes, but different plugins have their own highlight groups which is making this difficult.

Is there a way to set the terminal background color for all highlight groups of a specific color at the same time? I am trying to make all the white background components grey (color 254).

Answer (score 4):

You can probably loop the list returned by `getcompletion('','highlight')` and get the background with `synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID(l:thislistitem)), "bg")` (see `:h hlID()`).

Answer (score 1):

As [Bart mentioned](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14812/how-to-edit-all-vim-highlight-groups#14822), you can set all highlight groups with [`getcompletion('', 'highlight')`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/builtin.html#getcompletion()):

```vimscript
for l:highlightGroup in getcompletion('', 'highlight')
  execute "hi " . l:highlightGroup . " ctermfg=7 ctermbg=none guifg=White guibg=none"
endfor
```

This will overwrite the link from each highlight group to the other though. I didn't like that since I wanted to create a color scheme by starting from a clean state with *links intact*. This way, I only have to define custom colors for a few "root" highlight groups and not all of their descendants.

The following only changes root highlight groups, i.e., groups that link to themselves:

```vimscript
for l:highlightGroup in getcompletion('', 'highlight')

  " Get the group this highlight group links to
  let l:linkedGroup = GetLinkTarget(l:highlightGroup)
  " Only set the root highlight groups (those that don't link to others).
  " This leaves links intact
  if l:highlightGroup ==# l:linkedGroup
    execute "hi " . l:highlightGroup . " ctermfg=7 ctermbg=none guifg=White guibg=none"
  endif
endfor

function! GetLinkTarget(group)
    let l:groupID = hlID(a:group)
    " Get the group this highlight group links to
    let l:linkedGroupID = synIDtrans(l:groupID)
    let l:linkedGroupName = synIDattr(l:linkedGroupID, 'name')
    return l:linkedGroupName
endfunction
```

As an alternative to `getcompletion('', 'highlight')`, you can parse [`syntax list`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/syntax.html#:syn-list) which shows all highlight groups, where they link to, and when they're applied.